# "findstr" Windows command to exclude search in comment

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, findstr

How can i use findstr windows command to search for the string/character excluding the string/character commented inside the xhtml file?

Example : test.xtml

```
<html>
    <head/>
        <body>
             This is Test Code.  
             <!--Test Comment -->   
         </body>
</html>
```

findstr /X "Test" test.xtml.

This returns 2 lines instead i want only the uncommented line to be printed. (Expected Output::This is Test Code.)

Comment: Giving good details will help you get a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
findstr "Test" test.xtml |FINDSTR /v /r "<!.*>"
```

should filter out the comment-line, but your `findstr /x` does not act as you claim.

Comment: Thank you .It works for single line comment. How can i make it work for multiple line ?

Comment: Not that easy as batch commands are typically line-oriented. Probably better to try using a tool better suited to the task like `SED`. Theoretically, it could be done in batch, but you'd need to detect `<!` and then ignore all characters until a matching `>`, passing anything remaining to `findstr` to filter for the target string. I'd hesitate to say that it's impossible - just a lot of work that might not be particularly stable and best approached from another direction.